# GCC - how to tell linker not to skip unused sections

Tags: gcc, cmake, linker

My problem is following:

I am trying to write embedded application, which must have it's own linker script supplied (using arm-none-eabi-gcc compiler/linker).

embedded bootloader loads binary and starts at 0x8000 address, this is why I need a dedicated linker script, which allows me to put desired startup function into this address. Script's code is following:

```
MEMORY
{
    ram : ORIGIN = 0x8000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}

SECTIONS
{
    .start : { *(.start) } > ram
    .text : { *(.text*) } > ram
    .bss : { *(.bss*) } > ram
}
```

Having this what I want to do now is to have a function, that will be inserted into .start section, so that it's at the beginning of 0x8000. For this in my library I use following function:

```
__attribute__((section(".start"))) void notmain() {
    main();
}
```

This seems to be working fine, but later I link this library with function `notmain` with the project, which defines `main()` function. During the link process I can see `.start` section no more exists and `notmain` symbol
is totally missing. When I move notmain function out of the library (into the project) its'all fine.

My understanding is, that linker sees, that .start section is not used at all in my Application, which makes it skip all the sections. I already tried adding several attributes to function notmain such as (`__attribute__((used)) __attribute__((externally_visible))`) but it did not work too (notmain is still missing from the final binary).

CMake source code is following:

** Project **

```
project(AutomaticsControlExample)

enable_language(ASM)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set(SOURCES main.cpp PID.hpp)
set(DEPENDENCIES RPIRuntime PiOS)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${DEPENDENCIES})
add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_OBJDUMP} -D ${PROJECT_NAME}
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_OBJDUMP} -D ${PROJECT_NAME} > ${PROJECT_NAME}.list
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_OBJCOPY} ${PROJECT_NAME} -O binary ${PROJECT_NAME}.bin
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_OBJCOPY} ${PROJECT_NAME} -O ihex ${PROJECT_NAME}.hex)
```

** Library **

```
project(RPIRuntime)

enable_language(ASM)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set(LINKER_SCRIPT memmap)
set(LINKER_FLAGS "-T ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${LINKER_SCRIPT}")


set(SOURCES
        notmain.cpp
        assert.cpp)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${LINKER_FLAGS})
```

My question is: is there any way to prevent linker from omitting linking .start section?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you know, a static library is an `ar` archive of object files.

Suppose `libfoobar.a` contains just `foo.o` and `bar.o`. A linkage:

```
g++ -o prog a.o foo.o bar.o     # A
```

is *not* the same as the linkage:

```
g++ -o prog a.o -lfoobar.   # B
```

The linker unconditionally consumes every object file in the linkage sequence,
so in case `A`, it links `a.o`, `foo.o`, `bar.o` in `prog`.

The linker does *not* unconditionally consume every object file that is a member of
a static library in the linkage sequence. A static library is a way of offering to
the linker a bunch of object files from which to pick the ones it needs.

Suppose that `a.o` calls function `foo`, which is defined in `foo.o`, and that
`a.o` references nothing defined in `bar.o`.

In that case, the linker unconditionally links `a.o` into `prog`, after which
`prog` contains an undefined reference to `foo`, for which the linker needs a
definition. Next it reaches `libfoobar.a` and inspects the archive (by its index,
normally) to see if any member of the archive defines `foo`. It finds that `foo.o` does
so. So it extracts `foo.o` from the archive and links it. It needs no definitions
for any symbols defined in `bar.o`, so `bar.o` is not added to the linkage. The
linkage `B` is exactly the same as:

```
g++ -o prog a.o foo.o
```

Suppose on the other hand that `a.o` calls `bar`, which is defined in `bar.o`,
and references nothing defined in `foo.o`. In that case, the linkage `B` is
exactly the same as:

```
g++ -o prog a.o bar.o
```

So an object file that you insert into a static library for linkage with
your executable *will never be linked*, by default, unless it provides a definition
for at least one symbol that is referenced, but not defined, in an object file
that has already been linked.

Your function `notmain` is not referenced in the only object file, `main.o` that 
you are explicitly linking in your program. Therefore, when `main.o` is linked into your program,
the program  contains no undefined reference to `notmain`: the linker requires no definition
of `notmain` - it has never heard of `notmain` - and will not link any object file
from within a static library to obtain a definition of `notmain`. This has nothing
to do with linkage sections.

When linking an ordinary program with static libraries, as a matter of course
you do it like:

```
g++ -o prog main.o x.o ... -ly -lz ....
```

where one of the `*.o` files - say `main.o` - is the object file that defines the `main` function. You never
put `main.o` in one of the static libraries. That's because, in a ordinary program,
`main` is not called in any of the other object files you are explicitly linking,
so if `main.o` was in one of your libraries, the linkage:

```
g++ -o prog x.o ... -ly -lz ...
```

would have no need to find a definition of `main` at any of `-ly -lz ...`, and no definition
of `main` would be linked.

The case is just the same with your `notmain`. If you want it linked you can do one of:-

1. Add `-Wl,--undefined=notmain` to your linkage options (replacing `notmain` with
   the mangled name of `notmain`, for C++). This will make the linker assume it has an 
   undefined reference to `notmain` even though it hasn't seen any.
2. Add the command `EXTERN(notmain)` to your linker script (again with mangling
   for C++). This is equivalent to **1**.
3. Explicitly link an object file that defines `notmain`. Don't put it in a static library.

**3** is effectively what you did when you discovered that:

> When I move notmain function out of the library (into the project) its'all fine.

For **3**, however, you don't *need* to compile `notmain.cpp` in your project and any other
project that needs `notmain.o`. You can build it independently, install it
in `/usr/local/lib` and explicitly add  `/usr/local/lib/notmain.o` to the
linkage of your project. That would be following the example of GCC itself, which explicitly
links the `crt*.o` startup files of an ordinary program just by appending their
absolute names to the linkage, e.g.

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o
...
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
```

Comment: Thanks it's very explanatory answer. I finally understand why it does work the way it does. Thank you a lot !